# Bundle Does Not Exist: Symfony2

Tags: symfony, controller, bundle

I'm pretty new to Symfony2. I can't figure out what's going on. This code (set up to test if the bundle can be detected):

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Overlays\Animation;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Overlays\Marker;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

public function mapAction() {
    $map = $this->get ( 'ivory_google_map.map' );
        return $this->render ( 'KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Default:map.html.twig', array('map' => $map) );
  }
}
```

works, rendering a simple map, while this code (the real code that involves embedding a controller to render a map with data)

```
<?php
// localfarm/src/KrewMedia/Bundle/LocalFarmBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace KrewMedia\Bundle\LocalFarmBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Overlays\Animation;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Overlays\Marker;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

public function mapAction() {
    //$map = $this->get ( 'ivory_google_map.map' );
        return $this->render ( 'KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Default:maptest.html.twig');
  }
}
```

gives me this error: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Bundle "LocalFarmBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?") in KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Default:maptest.html.twig at line 3."

Both maptest.html.twig and map.html.twig are in the same folder in the LocalFarmBundle. I wonder why the bundle is found in the first piece of code but not in the second. The relevant routing is this

```
krew_media_local_farm_homepage:
    pattern:  /index
    defaults: { _controller: KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Default:index }

krew_media_local_farm_map:
     pattern:  /map
     defaults: { _controller: KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Default:map }

krew_media_basic_map:
     pattern:  /map/basic
     defaults: { _controller: KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Map:basic }
```

map.html.twig:

```
{{ google_map_container(map) }}

{{ google_map_js(map) }}
```

maptest.html.twig:

```
Map Test

{% render(controller( 'LocalFarmBundle:Map:basic')) %}
```

The controller for 'LocalFarmBundle:Map:basic':

```
public function basicAction() {
    // set up map
    $map = $this->get ( 'ivory_google_map.map' );

    // Get User geo info
    $user = $this->getUser ();

    if (isset ( $user )) { // check to see if logged in: map is useless without it
        $map->setAutoZoom ( true );
        $map->setStylesheetOption('width', '500px');
        $map->setStylesheetOption('height', '500px');


        $radius = 1;

        // get repository for user class
        $coordList = $this->container->get ( 'sylius.repository.user' )->findUsersNearUser ( $user, $radius );

        // set user marker

        $this->placeMarker ( $user, "/assets/img/home.png", $map );

        if (! empty ( $coordList )) {
            foreach ( $coordList as $geo ) {
                $this->placeMarker ( $geo, "/assets/img/neighbor.png", $map );
            }
        }

        // get furthest distance
        $dist = $this->getFurthestDistance ( $user, $coordList );

        // set invisible boundary markers
        $this->addBoundaries ( $user, $dist, $map );

        // render the map
    } else {
        echo "You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.";
    }


        return $this->render ( 'KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Default:map.html.twig', array (
            'map' => $map 
    ) );
```

Any help would be appreciated in figuring out this problem.

Comment: Did you enabled it in `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: The bundle is enabled; hence the first code works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`render` tag requires full name of bundle, so change

```
{% render(controller( 'LocalFarmBundle:Map:basic')) %}
```

to

```
{% render(controller( 'KrewMediaLocalFarmBundle:Map:basic')) %}
```